# What do you call images you write drawn on the floor for rituals?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I know this is a pentagram, but I am not sure if there's a general term for images drawn on the floor to perform some kind of ritual. Doesn't have to be a satanic or occult ritual, but any ritual.

Comment: If [playing hopscotch](https://www.parents.com/fun/activities/hopscotch/) counts as a "ritual", it's probably worth noting that there is no generally-recognised term for the chalked-out area (some people might called the Hopscotch one a "court", but that's just [***faute de mieux***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faute%20de%20mieux)). In all the "satanic or occult ritual" movie contexts I've ever seen, it's just "the circle" (or maybe pentagram if that's what it is).

Comment: You call them: ritualistic images drawn on the floor or ground.

Comment: No, someone found the answer. It was sigil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **[sigil](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sigil)** is a word meaning "an inscribed or painted symbol considered to have magical power." The picture you posted might also generically be called a "[magic circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_circle)."

Answer (score 1):

It could be called a **device**.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/device) has

> **b** something fanciful, elaborate, or intricate in design

and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/device) has

> **2** a drawing or design

The term is also appropriate because the drawing has a purpose, so it is a device in the more usual sense of the word.